# Civicrm with drupal 8 generating error while testing with behat

Tags: drupal-8

I have installed civicrm with drupal8 and I am trying to implement behat in my site. When I am trying to test my site for as logged in user using behat feature file I am getting an notice Notice: Undefined index: q in /var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/libraries/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/DrupalBase.php line 487 (Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException).

Below is the debug backtrace output:

## 0  CRM_Utils_System_DrupalBase->postURL() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/libraries/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:502]

```
  │ #1  CRM_Utils_System::postURL() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/libraries/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm.php:289]
  │ #2  HTML_QuickForm->HTML_QuickForm() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/libraries/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:71]
  │ #3  HTML_QuickForm_Page->HTML_QuickForm_Page() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/libraries/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:214]
  │ #4  CRM_Core_Form->__construct() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/libraries/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:459]
  │ #5  CRM_Core_Controller->addPages() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/libraries/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller/Simple.php:81]
  │ #6  CRM_Core_Controller_Simple->__construct() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/libraries/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php:794]
  │ #7  CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getEditHTML() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/modules/civicrm/civicrm.user.inc:29]
  │ #8  civicrm_user_insert()
  │ #9  call_user_func_array() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php:394]
  │ #10 Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php:172]
  │ #11 Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->invokeHook() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php:385]
  │ #12 Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeHook() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php:469]
  │ #13 Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPostSave() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php:271]
  │ #14 Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPostSave() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php:394]
  │ #15 Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:746]
  │ #16 Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php:340]
  │ #17 Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/drupal/drupal-driver/src/Drupal/Driver/Cores/Drupal8.php:108]
  │ #18 Drupal\Driver\Cores\Drupal8->userCreate() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/drupal/drupal-driver/src/Drupal/Driver/DrupalDriver.php:102]
  │ #19 Drupal\Driver\DrupalDriver->userCreate() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/drupal/drupal-extension/src/Drupal/DrupalExtension/Context/RawDrupalContext.php:363]
  │ #20 Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\RawDrupalContext->userCreate() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/drupal/drupal-extension/src/Drupal/DrupalExtension/Context/DrupalContext.php:52]
  │ #21 Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext->assertAuthenticatedByRole()
  │ #22 call_user_func_array() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/Handler/RuntimeCallHandler.php:99]
  │ #23 Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler->executeCall() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/Handler/RuntimeCallHandler.php:54]
  │ #24 Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler->handleCall() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/CallCenter.php:125]
  │ #25 Behat\Testwork\Call\CallCenter->handleCall() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/CallCenter.php:80]
  │ #26 Behat\Testwork\Call\CallCenter->makeCall() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeStepTester.php:125]
  │ #27 Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeStepTester->testDefinition() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeStepTester.php:73]
  │ #28 Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeStepTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableStepTester.php:74]
  │ #29 Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableStepTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingStepTester.php:73]
  │ #30 Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingStepTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/StepContainerTester.php:59]
  │ #31 Behat\Behat\Tester\StepContainerTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeScenarioTester.php:76]
  │ #32 Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeScenarioTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableScenarioTester.php:74]
  │ #33 Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableScenarioTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingScenarioTester.php:103]
  │ #34 Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingScenarioTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeFeatureTester.php:83]
  │ #35 Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeFeatureTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableFeatureTester.php:72]
  │ #36 Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableFeatureTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingFeatureTester.php:71]
  │ #37 Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingFeatureTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeSuiteTester.php:63]
  │ #38 Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeSuiteTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Hook/Tester/HookableSuiteTester.php:73]
  │ #39 Behat\Testwork\Hook\Tester\HookableSuiteTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingSuiteTester.php:72]
  │ #40 Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingSuiteTester->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeExercise.php:71]
  │ #41 Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeExercise->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingExercise.php:70]
  │ #42 Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingExercise->test() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Cli/ExerciseController.php:146]
  │ #43 Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->testSpecifications() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Cli/ExerciseController.php:108]
  │ #44 Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->execute() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Command.php:63]
  │ #45 Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command->execute() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259]
  │ #46 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:878]
  │ #47 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:195]
  │ #48 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php:102]
  │ #49 Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->doRun() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:126]
  │ #50 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() called at [/var/www/html/drupal8aritnew/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat:31]
```

Can anyone help me understanding what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know which version of D8 you tried with. The readme says "It it currently verified to work against Drupal 8 beta 14 and CiviCRM 4.7"

I am not clear if your issue is purely with Behat.

We have not had a chance yet to find the bugs that might have been introduced with Drupal 8 rc1.

If you can help progress this please do report back. If you can help fund the ongoing work of getting CiviCRM working with Drupal 8 then please consider donating via this [MIH](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=71).